# how to show hidden divs inside list

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have a `ul` list with each `li` constructed like this:

```
<li class="A">list-item
  <div>1</div>
  <div class="B">2
     <div class="C">3</div>
  </div>
</li>
```

Where div with class `.C` has the CSS property `display:none;`

I would like to  show hidden divs on li hover, but I would like it to show only on active li item. So when I hover the `li` item it shows only that list item hidden div.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could achieve it in pure CSS, using a selector such as `.A:hover div.C { display:block; }`

[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/AMgYL/1/)

---

Example code:

**HTML:**

```
<li class="A">list-item
  <div>1</div>
  <div class="B">2
     <div class="C">3</div>
  </div>   
</li>

<li class="A">list-item
  <div>1</div>
  <div class="B">2
     <div class="C">3</div>
  </div>    
</li>
```

**CSS:**

```
div.C {
    display:none;
}

.A:hover div.C {
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: +1. Just a detail, poster says div of class C have disply:none

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using jQuery and CSS.

HTML code:

```
<li class="Active">list-item
    <div>1</div>
    <div class="B">2
    <div class="C hideDiv">3</div>
    </div>
</li>
```

CSS code:

```
.hideDiv{display:none;}
```

Jquery Code:

```
$('li.Active').mouseover(function(){    
    $(this).find('div.C').removeClass('hideDiv');
});

$('li.Active').mouseout(function(){    
    $(this).find('div.C').addClass('hideDiv');
});
```